# smooth out corners of a 3-point line strip

Tags: c++, math, opengl, curve, spline

I have a line strip defined by 3 points, each having an x and y coordinate.

I'm trying to smooth out the middle (point 2) corner as shown in the picture below:

[image]

the gray line is the original line strip and the black one is the smoothed-out one.
The smoothed out area should be constant across multiple values (as in it is not dependent on length of the line between p1 and p2 or p2 and p3).

I've originally been using bezier curves and a simple spline, however that did not do the trick since the smooth curve was obviously not same across multiple values.

How can I do this?

Comment: I was just about to suggest Bezier curves.  But you lost me when you said "the smooth curve was obviously not same across multiple values".  Maybe this part is not so _obvious_ to me.  Can you explain in more detail why Bezier didn't do the trick?

Comment: Same here: Could you explain further "The smoothed out area should be constant across multiple values (as in it is not dependent on length of the line between p1 and p2 or p2 and p3)."

Comment: If you're satisfied with keeping the shape of the "corner" constant as the line lengths grow to infinity, you could simply either choose the original end point or the point on the corresponding line at a distance `x` from the intersection, whichever is closer to the intersection, using straight lines for the rest, if necessary. If you want to do do this for arbitrarily short lines, you're probably limited to the original straight lines, since as the lengths converge to zero you'll need to get closer and closer to the intersection.

Comment: Lets see if you mean this : Pick 2 points on each line that are the same distance to the corner. On those points draw two lines at right angles to the lines you already have (normal vectors pointing bottom left). They will cross at a point which will be the center of a circle, part this circle will then be the smoothed corner.

Comment: You could take center point of each segment and make the bezier between them. This way consecutive lines will not interact between them.

Comment: for the people that asked about the bezier curve thing: If I have a large enough distance between my control points the "curve" becomes different from a bezier curves with different control point distances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick 2 points on each line that are the same distance to the corner. On those points draw two lines at right angles to the lines you already have (normal vectors pointing bottom left). They will cross at a point which will be the center of a circle, part this circle will then be the smoothed corner.

[image: Rounded corner]

Comment: This however only works when lines are long enough to reach that perpendicular to the radius point.

Comment: yup, its kind of guesswork based on the input we had ;) But you could start decreasing d if lines become too short.

Comment: this seems to work, thanks for your help!